# get entire json object via kubectl with filter on field value

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So the following query:

```
kubectl get mycustomresource -A -o json --field-selector status.state=failed
```

returns this:

```
field selector "status.state=failed": field label "status.state" not supported
```

and there's no way I'm going to be able to change that to be supported.

Question: how do I get the entire json object for all objects where a field is a certain value without using `--field-selector`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-o jsonpath="{._______}"`

Example:

```
kubectl get mycustomresource -A -o jsonpath=${.status[state='failed']}"
```

You may need to use some wild cards if your looking for items at the bottom of a json document hierarchy.